# YA book about a boy who can control tornadoes, and is the last of his kind

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I believe I read this book during my sophomore year of HS in 2016, basically a boy who can control tornadoes loses his family at a young age to an organization that murders them because they’re part of the wind elemental clan that is being wiped out (their society has people of different elements like avatar). He has to be relocated to live with another family somewhere else.

A girl he used to know when he was a kid soon finds him and tells him about who he really is, and explains that he’s one of the last of his kind. She also tells him that the king has people looking to kill him, because his death will mean that the king would have mastered every element and would become more powerful.

I explained it weird because there’s a lot I don’t remember, but hopefully someone has read this! I might be wrong about them being separated by elements but the MC was definitely the last of his kind.

Answer (score 2):

Could this be [*Let the Sky Fall*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13445306-let-the-sky-fall) by Shannon Messenger?

> *Vane Weston should have died in the category-five tornado that killed his parents. Instead, he woke up in a pile of rubble with no memories of his past — except one: a beautiful, dark-haired girl standing in the winds. She swept through his dreams ever since, and he clings to the hope that she's real.*
>
> *Audra is real, but she isn't human. She's a sylph, an air elemental who can walk on the wind, translate its alluring songs, even twist it into a weapon. She's also a guardian — Vane's guardian — and has sworn an oath to protect him at all costs.*
>
> *When a hasty mistake reveals their location to the enemy who murdered both their families, Audra has just days to help Vane unlock his memories. And as the storm winds gather, Audra and Vane start to realize that the greatest danger might not be the warriors coming to destroy them, but the forbidden romance growing between them*

[image]